# Variable with Setter or Boolean Getter

Tags: java, c++, coding-style

Suppose I have an instance variable called isConnected and a method called checkConnection. I can either have:

An instance variable `isConnected` and a method `void checkConnection()` that sets the `isConnected` variable.

OR

Only a boolean method `bool checkConnection()`.

I feel that having an instance variable is pointless. Every time that you WANT to check the connection, you have to call `checkConnection()` anyway before even using `isConnected`. Why not just have the boolean method?

It's a question of semantics, really.

Sorry if there is no proper category to put this question.

Comment: @RajnikantPatel Did you even read the question?

Comment: Yes, the variable is not necessary [in a situation like described here]

Comment: @Toni_Entranced, We do not need to have an instance variable in your case.

Comment: @deviantfan I did read the question, and I agree with Rajnikant. There's no way to give a coherent answer without seeing the whole class.  There are cases where an instance variable would be useful, and cases where it might not be.  And we need to see the whole class to determine which.

Comment: (even more, having the variable includes the risk of using it (the old value) without calling the check method, and doing wrong things because of that)

Comment: @ajb Could you give an example where the variable is useful [given that the OP explicitly wants a fresh value each time]?

Comment: @deviantfan Suppose there's some other method that does something with the connection, like reading a message, and the desired behavior is that read() looks at the result of the previous checkConnection() and throws an exception if the check failed.  In that case you might want a boolean method that also saves its result for future use (in a *private* variable).

Comment: This question is a difficult to answer. The OP presents two options, without specifying how they came up with those options (what the specific requirements are, what tradeoffs are expected, etc); and then posits that one of the options is pointless. The only specific we're told about the instance-variable approach is that the OP feels that it's pointless, and then we're asked whether it's pointless. This question boils down to "isn't it pointless to always have methods return void, and then have a separate method to get at their would-be return value?" to which the answer is obviously "yes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a single threaded system I would prefer the second approach, the one not including a `isConnected` variable.

In a multi threaded system (incl. a distributed one) I would prefer the first approach, the one with `isConnected` and `bool checkConnection()`. You can synchronise access to the variable, as well as to any associated logic (or a critical section). As an example, you could implement [Test and Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) using a method.

Comment: What does this mean?  Which one is the "method" approach (given that both approaches involve methods)?  Which one is the "simpler" approach (which might be a matter of opinion--they're both pretty simple)?

Comment: Valid comment, thank you. Updated.